# Schema has not been registered error on population

Tags: node.js, mongoose

When I'm trying to populate , this error is coming: 
" MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "

My models:
/models/course.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var User = require('./user')

var courseSchema = Schema({
    courseName:String,
    price:Number,
    type:String,
    _offeredBy:{type:Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref:User}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Course",courseSchem
```

models/user.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');
var findOrCreate = require('mongoose-findorcreate')
var Course = require('./course')

var userSchema = Schema({
    email:{type:String},
    password:{type:String},
    courseOffered:[{type:Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref:Course}]
});


module.exports = mongoose.model('User',userSchema);
```

routes/index.js

```
var Course = require('../models/course');
var User = require('../models/user');
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/user/profile',isLoggedIn,function(req,res,next){
res.render('user/profile',{csrfToken:req.csrfToken(),message:""})
});
router.post('/user/profile',isLoggedIn,function(req,res,next){
var courseInfo = req.body;
var newCourse = new Course();
newCourse.courseName = courseInfo.coursename;
newCourse.price = courseInfo.price;
newCourse.type = courseInfo.type;
newCourse._offeredBy = req.user;
newCourse.save(function(err,result){
if(err){
  res.redirect('/user/profile');
}
});
Course
.findOne({courseName:courseInfo.coursename})
.populate('_offeredBy')
.exec(function(err,course){
if(err){
  res.redirect('/user/profile');
}
});

});
```

Course is getting saved in the database, but the error is coming due to pouplating. I'm not writing the app.js, mongodb connections are made in app.js file.

Comment: Is that what your actual code looks like? `module.exports = mongoose.model("Course",courseSchem `. Code you posted is missing something, but given the error you likely have a spelling mistake at least in the actual code.

Comment: No, that was a mistake on posting,module.exports = mongoose.model("Course",courseSchema);

Comment: Please correct your question as posted and check the naming again. The error suggests you actually have a schema name mispelled. Hence it is not registered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your models are trying to load another model which itself then tries to load the other model.

In your schemas you should set the refs as strings like this:

```
var courseSchema = Schema({
    courseName: String,
    price: Number,
    type: String,
    _offeredBy: { type:Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }
});
```

```
var userSchema = Schema({
    email: String,
    password: String,
    courseOffered: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Course' }]
});
```

You can then remove the lines to require the other model within each model file. They are both loaded in 'routes/index.js' before being used.

Note: newCouse.save() is asynchronous so you should do you Course.findOne().populate() inside the 'save' callback.